# Undefined offset warning in php

Tags: php

I am doing this simple thing in php whenever i run the code i got an error

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\colorconverter.php on line 37
```

this is the code that generated that error

```
function colorConverter($color)
{
         preg_match_all("/(\d+\.+\d+)/", $color, $rgba);
         list($rgba[0], $rgba[1], $rgba[2], $rgba[3]) = $rgba[1] ;


        $rgbaValues = array("RED"=>$rgba[0], "GREEN"=>$rgba[1], "BLUE"=>$rgba[2], "ALPHA"=>$rgba[3]);
        return $rgbaValues; 
}
```

although it return correct value but why it still show an error

Comment: got an error at this line list($rgba[0], $rgba[1], $rgba[2], $rgba[3]) = $rgba[1] ;

Comment: probably are you calling `colorConverter` twice in your code when `$color` is not set

Answer (score 1):

It should be because you do not have $rgba array with 4 elements from the beginning.

Preg match all returns 2 elements `0` and `1` where second (`1`) is array which I guess is `$rgba[1][0]`, `$rgba[1][1]`, `$rgba[1][2]` and so on. You are trying to override `$rgba[1]` with its child elements.

Either declare new array and fill it with 4 empty elements, or not apply array elements in `list()` there should be variables:

```
list($rgba1, $rgba2, $rgba3, $rgba4) = $rgba[1] ;
```